# Is it possible to define an int32 value in javascript console?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, types, int32

Do I understand right that it is impossible to define and store an int32 value in the mongodb javascript console? So if I want to do so a have no choice but to write a program in Java or other language with well-typed driver interface?

The only more or less clear explanation I could find is [BUG #854](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-854) in mongodb's JIRA. But I just can't believe that such a simple and vital feature is avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's even worse than that, if you retrieve data in the JS console and then write it back to the DB, it will convert interegers to floats.

<strike>AFAIK the new feature to fix this is still not implemented</strike>. The new feature was implemented in 1.9.1:

```
var intValue = NumberInt(3);
```

Comment: I had this issue, the answer from Doug W below worked for me though

Comment: yes, they fixed it a couple of weeks after I wrote that... updated.

Answer (score 4):

Just as an update, the following function is working okay for me. The resulting field is of type Int32

```
var intValue = NumberInt(3);
```

Comment: Which version are you using? 2.0?